# Visual Studio for mac - loading existing branches using git

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio, branch, visual-studio-mac

I installed visual studio for mac. 
I can clone a github repository, create new branches and revert to master without problems.

The problem I have is when I'm using version control.

I can see the log from the git project and all the comited changes.
But I can not figure out how to create a new branch from these.

Visual studio for mac is fairly new and I could not find any information about this on the Microsoft Developer Network.

Comment: Did you try from the main menu opening Version Control - Manage Branches and Remotes? From there you can create a new branch using the New button and have it track an existing branch.

Comment: I tried this, but I can only tack local branches. The same project works fine on visual studio on windows.. @MattWard